# Covert a dataframe into a matrix form

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, matrix

I have a dataset looks like this:

```
state VDM  MDM  OM  
AP     1    2   5   
GOA    1    2   1   
GU     1    2   4   
KA     1    5   1   
MA     1    4   4
```

I have tried this code:

```
aMat=df1000.as_matrix()
print(aMat)
```

here df1000 is the dataset.

But the above code gives this output:

```
[['AP' 1 2 5]
 ['GOA' 1 2 1]
 ['GU' 1 2 4]
 ['KA' 1 5 1]
 ['MA' 1 4 4]]
```

I want to create a 2d list or matrix which looks like this:

```
[[1, 2, 5], [1, 2, 1], [1,  2,  4], [1, 5, 1], [1, 4, 4]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`df.iloc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df.iloc[:,1:].to_numpy()
```

---

```
array([[1, 2, 5],
   [1, 2, 1],
   [1, 2, 4],
   [1, 5, 1],
   [1, 4, 4]], dtype=int64)
```

Or for string matrix:

```
df.astype(str).iloc[:,1:].to_numpy()
```

---

```
array([['1', '2', '5'],
   ['1', '2', '1'],
   ['1', '2', '4'],
   ['1', '5', '1'],
   ['1', '4', '4']], dtype=object)
```

Note why we are not using `as_matrix()`

> ".as_matrix will be removed in a future version. Use .values instead."

Answer (score 1):

Select all columns without first by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and convert integer values to strings by [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html), last convert to numpy array by [`to_numpy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html) or [`DataFrame.values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html):

```
#pandas 0.24+
aMat=df1000.iloc[:, 1:].astype(str).to_numpy()
#pandas below
aMat=df1000.iloc[:, 1:].astype(str).values
```

Or remove first column by [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
#pandas 0.24+
aMat=df1000.drop('state', axis=1).astype(str).to_numpy()
#pandas below
aMat=df1000.drop('state', axis=1).astype(str).values
```